# Would it be possible to add the color formatting for omnet++ tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting

I have started being active in the StackOverflow `omnet++` tag.

What I have noticed is that, when some question is posted to the `omnet++` tag also coupled with the `c++` tag the code-snipped formatting in that question get coloured. Such as here: [How to implement a replay attack using AODV protocol in omnet++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404458/how-to-implement-a-replay-attack-using-aodv-protocol-in-omnet)

Whereas, if the question is tagged with the `omnet++` tag (combined with others) but excluding the `c++` tag, there code-snippet gets no colouring. Such as here: [Overriding Functions with omnet++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277561/omnet-overriding-functions)

I wonder if it would be possible to add the "colouring feature" to the `omnet++` tag as well. So that there is a clear distinction when a question is omnet++ specific vs. c++ & omnet++ combined. While the advantage of colouring remains in the both cases.

PS: this is my first post in Meta forum. I apologize if I have not respected any rules of which I am not aware of.

Comment: omnet++, like most libraries, probably won't get a syntax-highlighting-hint. That is actually *a good thing*: It encourages properly tagging with the language instead of only the library used.

Comment: Unfortunately SO doesn't have control of the code coloring engine IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ SO associates languages with tags: If you use the [C++] tag, you get C++ coloring by default, if you use the [java] tag, you get java coloring by default etc. Also, you can use hints like `<!-- language: lang-csharp -->` or `<!-- language-all: lang-cpp -->` to override this default.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yeah, I know well. But this is interpreted by external code (some open source google stuff I think), and the SO staff doesn't really have the control (or time) to add new `<!-- language: -->` comment tags with this engine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think what the OP asks for here is that, omnet++ being a C++ library, questions tagged with this tag should get C++ highlighting by default. But now you mention this I'm not that sure about my interpretation anymore (looks like there's some kind of DSL in that lib)...